# Flash Flex variables are null when added in String

Tags: flash, variables, apache-flex, null, actionscript

Hi I am new to Flash and am using Flash Builder 4.6

I have a form with an email and password like this

```
<s:Form x="33" y="290" width="228" height="97">
    <s:FormItem label="Email"  >
        <s:TextInput id="emailText"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem label="Password"   >
        <s:TextInput id="passwordText"/>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
```

And I want to create an XML file to POST and have done this

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[


        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.controls.Text;

        public var  strXmlTextInput1:String = "<dfapi><email>" + emailText + "</email><password>" + passwordText + "</password><duration>0</duration></dfapi>";

        protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void

        {

            Operation1Result.token = session.Operation1(strXmlTextInput1);
            Alert.show(strXmlTextInput1);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

But the XML that is POSTed has  the variables emailText and passwordText have been passed as null. It works fine if I replace the variables with actual values.

What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: Use `emailText.text` and `passwordText.text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write:

```
public var strXmlTextInput1:String = "<dfapi><email>" + emailText + "</email><password>" +
    passwordText + "</password><duration>0</duration></dfapi>";
```

you are referring to the component **s:TextInput** named by you as *emailText*, so the implicit conversion to `String` returns `NULL`.

To use the text appears in video you must use the `text` property as follow:

```
public var strXmlTextInput1:String = "<dfapi><email>" + emailText.text + 
    "</email><password>" + passwordText.text + 
    "</password><duration>0</duration></dfapi>";
```

Comment: Yes that was the right answer. Many thanks. Simple when you know.

Comment: Have a nice day ;)